# delete null values from an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, null

I have an array in php $arr("ABC","","XYZ","",""). now i want to trim the null values in the array and want $arr("ABC","XYZ"). And the element number must also be manipulated likewise which means "XYZ" must have the key value as 1 after trimming. How do we do it? Thanks in advance! Cheers!

Comment: `$result = array_values(array_filter($array));`

Comment: Note that those aren't null values that you're removing, they're empty strings

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

> Filters elements of an array using a callback function. If no callback is supplied, all entries of array equal to FALSE (see [converting to boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting)) will be removed.

```
$arr = array_filter($arr);
```